# What to do with answers that are not best practise

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I notice answers that would put heavy load on a server or are not at all best practise.

For example:

> Object saves / loads in for loops.
>
> Loading JQuery in Magento because it is "easier".
>
> Nested ifs and loops.
>
> Using rewrites when an observer is easily useable.

Because i do not know how to respond to it I have left a comment last time.
My question is should we flag stuff like this to watch over the quality of the answers?

Comment: I didn't get the memo that using jQuery was bad practice.

Comment: @psphan using jquery is not bad practice but implementing it for 1 or 2 features that prototype can handle is. Why would you add a library to an environment when the build in library can do the same in basicly the same way? + You could have compatibility issues when there are several extensions using a different jQuery version, this is why I usually advice people to avoid the use of it in Magento.

Comment: I guess that makes sense from some certain points of view, though not in any case I have experienced. The benefits greatly outweigh these drawbacks. I would rather add a library and use existing tools than rewrite those tools for a different library and have to maintain two codebases. I get what you mean, though.

Answer (score 3):

Not flag. Downvote and explain the problem in comment.

Comment: Thing is, these answers are also accepted from time to time and get a few upvotes from less knowledgeable ppl. Even if i downvote and comment, its still in the spotlight and might still mislead people.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Downvote and warn people is the best you can do

Answer (score 0):

If something is going to get under your skin as not being a "best practice", I think the best way to handle it is to let someone know (not that they will *understand*) why it's a problem and try and provide a better solution.

I don't think a question or answer necessarily deserves a downvote (though it might). There are some perfectly valid reasons to do things that aren't best practice. I will load models/collections and iterate over them inside of a .phtml file and have no hesitation that what I'm doing is wrong. Of course, I won't leave that code permanent, but there are times when doing something the "wrong" way is the best way to handle something that is only temporary.